# The responsive development tools on chrome or safari seem to render the page wrong

Tags: html, css, iphone, developer-tools

I'm building a web app using the create-react-app toolkit. I'm trying to make my website as mobile friendly as possible. I'm initially designing for an iPhone 5 because that is one of the smallest phones around and because it's the phone I have. When I render my website using Chrome or Safari developer tools, the page renders very much different than when I open the page directly on my iPhone. Both Chrome and Safari developer tools have iPhone5 viewpoint defined as 320x568 however that doesn't account for the bar at the top and bottom of the page. In Safari the ACTUAL viewpoint size for my iPhone5 is 320x460 when the page first loads, and after you start scrolling down it expands to 320x529. I figured this out using:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    console.log('width: ' + window.innerWidth);
    console.log('height: ' + window.innerHeight);
});
```

HOWEVER, even when I change the size of the viewport in my developer tools to those values (both Chrome and Safari), it still looks different than the actual iPhone.

I've been unable to find similar problems/solutions to this problem on stack or anywhere else and I want to know if there's a way to make sure the page is viewed correctly on all devices?

Thank you in advance

[iPhone 5 Web Design Specs](http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/iphone-5-web-design/)

Comment: I've now checked this with an iPhone 6 using the same methods to get viewpoint size and the same problem occurs. I've noticed when holding the phone upright, the actual phone will show just a little bit less than the developer mode does (because of scaling text etc. this is not a simple size ratio). When holding the phone sideways, the text on the phone is MUCH bigger and as a result you see much less on the screen.
In sideways mode, images scale almost exactly the same, but in profile mode, images are slightly smaller on the actual phone.